# Can readLines be executed in parallel within R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is it possible to iterative over a single text file on a single multi-core machine in parallel with R?  For context, the text file is somewhere between 250-400MB of JSON output.

EDIT:

Here are some code samples I have been playing around with.  To my surprise, parallel processing did not win - just basic lapply - but this could be due to user error on my part.  In addition, when trying to read a number of large files, my machine choked.

```
## test on first 100 rows of 1 twitter file
library(rjson)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(plyr)
N = 100
library(rbenchmark)
mc.cores <- detectCores()
benchmark(lapply(readLines(FILE, n=N, warn=FALSE), fromJSON),
          llply(readLines(FILE, n=N, warn=FALSE), fromJSON),
          mclapply(readLines(FILE, n=N, warn=FALSE), fromJSON),
          mclapply(readLines(FILE, n=N, warn=FALSE), fromJSON, 
                   mc.cores=mc.cores),
          foreach(x=readLines(FILE, n=N, warn=FALSE)) %do% fromJSON(x),
          replications=100)
```

Here is a second code sample

```
parseData <- function(x) {
  x <- tryCatch(fromJSON(x), 
                error=function(e) return(list())
                )
  ## need to do a test to see if valid data, if so ,save out the files
  if (!is.null(x$id_str)) {
    x$created_at <- strptime(x$created_at,"%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
    fname <- paste("rdata/",
                   format(x$created_at, "%m"),
                   format(x$created_at, "%d"),
                   format(x$created_at, "%Y"),
                   "_",
                   x$id_str,
                   sep="")
    saveRDS(x, fname)
    rm(x, fname)
    gc(verbose=FALSE)
  }
}

t3 <- system.time(lapply(readLines(FILES[1], n=-1, warn=FALSE), parseData))
```

Comment: Is the problem in reading the JSON file or in parsing the JSON file?

Comment: Neither.  My machine eventually freezes when I try to use a simple for loop.  I have attempted to run a function against each JSON entry, save out seperate rds files to read back in, etc, etc.  With every option, I am also conscious of the memory usage and attempt to optimize and clean when possible.  Some ideas were awful, but in the end, I want to figure out ways to "analyze" larger datasets just with Base R, ignoring the fact that better solutions exist for the moment.

Comment: A reproducible example would make it much easier for us to provide feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on what the problem actually is: reading the file in parallel, or processing the file in parallel.

## Reading in parallel

You could split the JSON file into multiple input files and read them in parallel, e.g. using the `plyr` functions combined with a parallel backend:

```
result = ldply(list.files(pattern = ".json"), readJSON, .parallel = TRUE)
```

Registering a backend can probably be done using the `parallel` package which is now integrated in base R. Or you can use the `doSNOW` package, see [this post on my blog](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/11/14/parallelization-using-plyr-loading-objects-and-packages-into-worker-nodes/) for details.

## Processing in parallel

In this scenario your best bet is to read the entire dataset into a vector of characters, split the data and then use a parallel backend combined with e.g. the `plyr` functions.

Comment: Not a bad idea. And if you're looking for a way to chop up the file, take a look at the UNIX `split` command.

Comment: @JeffAllen Interesting.  Didn't really think of pre-processing the data ahead of time with commands. Not an expert at the command line by any stretch, but the more I poke around, I see how powerful a few commands can be.

Answer (score 2):

probably not with `readLines()` due to the nature of non-parallel file-system IO. Of course, if you're using a parallel NFS or something like HDFS, then this restriction won't apply. But assuming you're on a "standard" architecture, it won't be feasible to parallelize your `readLine()` calls.

Your best bet would probably be to read in the entire file seeing as <500MB will probably fit in memory, then parallelize the processing once you're object is already read in.

Comment: +1, but with a bit of work you could probably get parallel `readLines` by assigning line numbers to each worker that they need to read from a given file connection.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra can you give an example of how that might be done in the simplest possible case?  :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico I don't have time right now, but I think it is not trivial, and it very well might not work.